# TypeScript Property Decorators

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, decorator

I'm looking to isolate model validation within the model class itself, without having to hard-code required states (our designer guys don't know what is required, just that they need to hook up properties). I'm trying the property decorator path without much luck. The constructor overwrites what the decorator sets. Is this even possible, should I go about it another way?

**model.ts**

```
@Required
name: string;

hobbies: string;

constructor(dto?: any) {
    this.name = dto.name; // This clears my "required" property
    this.hobbies = dto.hobbies;
}
```

**decorator.ts**

```
function Required(target: any, key: string) {
    Object.defineProperty(target, "required", { value: true });
}
```

What I am hoping to accomplish...

***.html**

```
<input name="name" [(ngModel)]="model.name" [required]="model.name.hasOwnProperty('required')">
```

I've also tried playing with the String prototype itself to initialize this property, but the constructor still clears anything that gets set.

```
String.prototype["required"] = false;
```

Comment: I am not following how you intend to use/create this. Could you create an [mcve] on https://stackblitz.com? I realize the code won't work but it will convey the intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hold extra information in the property like that. A property when assigned will be replaced by the new value, nothing of what you assign not the prototype of the class (and `target` is the `prototype` not an instance of the class) will be accessible once you assign a new value.

A solution would be to add an extra property, lets call it `meta` which could hold this metadata (and other property metadata as needed). You can even type it correctly using mapped types. This solution is pretty close to your desired outcome:

```
class Model {
    readonly meta!: Metadata<Model>
    @Required
    name: string;

    hobbies: string;

    constructor(dto?: any) {
        this.name = dto.name; // This clears my "required" property
        this.hobbies = dto.hobbies;
    }
}
type Metadata<T> = Partial<Record<keyof T, PropertyMetadata>>
type PropertyMetadata = {
    required?: boolean
}
function Required<T extends { meta: Metadata<T> }, TKey extends keyof T>(target: T, key: TKey) {
    let meta = target.meta || (target.meta = {});
    let propMeta = meta[key] || (meta[key] = {})
    propMeta!.required = true
}

console.log(new Model({}).meta.name!.required);
```

Note that `meta` can be undefined if you don't have any metadata. And the metadata for a property could likewise be undefined so in the angular template you should access it using `?`: `model.meta?.name?.required`. You could also do some fancier stuff assigning a `Proxy` instead of `{}` to `meta` but I went the simple route here.